# How did Henchard change after the auction incident?

Tags: character-analysis, thomas-hardy, the-mayor-of-casterbridge

In the novel *The Mayor of Casterbridge* by Thomas Hardy, how was Henchard a changed person after the auction incident?

Comment: Hello Sumamah and welcome to Literature SE. To get the best out of the site, it is recommended that you take the [tour] and especially read the [Help] pages on [asking questions](https://literature.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). To get a good reception and helpful answers you will need to ask a much more detailed question and tell us what thoughts you already have and what further information you hope people can offer. At the moment your question is attracting closure votes, but if you can improve it, it will stay open and attract useful answers.